# Android: Show/hide preference on checking/unchecking other CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, preference, checkboxpreference, preferencefragment

Im trying to accomplish such a thing:
when I check CheckBoxPreference 'A' the other preference ('B') shows below the A, 
when I uncheck 'A', preference 'B' hides...

So generally speaking it should work just like dependency but not only enabling/disabling th preference B, but hiding it.

This is what i came up with:

```
prefA = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("preference_A");
prefA.setChecked(false);

prefB = findPreference("preference_B");
category.removePreference(prefB);

prefA.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

        boolean switchedOn = (Boolean)newValue;
        if (switchedOn)
        {
            Log.d("pref_test", "prefA checked");

            category.addPreference(prefB);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("pref_test", "prefA UNchecked");

            prefB = findPreference("preference_B");
            category.removePreference(prefB);   
        }

        return switchedOn;  
    }
});
```

prefA and prefB have been defined earlier as PreferenceFragment class fields.

The problem is  that it works fine only for 2 clicks and my logs say:

```
prefA checked
prefA UNchecked
prefA UNchecked
```

Like it was calling onPreferenceChangeListener twice for unchecking (obviously resulting in .removePreference(prefB) method returning null).

Any idea on solving the issue?

Comment: try returning true instead of switchedOn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would it not work doing something like this?

```
prefA = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("preference_A");
prefA.setChecked(false);

prefB = findPreference("preference_B");
category.removePreference(prefB);

prefA.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

        boolean switchedOn = (Boolean)newValue;
        if (switchedOn) {
             Log.d("pref_test", "prefA checked");

             category.addPreference(prefB);

        } else {
            Log.d("pref_test", "prefA UNchecked");

            prefB = findPreference("preference_B");
            category.removePreference(prefB);   
        }

        return true;  
    }
});
```

Comment: yep, that return statement was the problem (still need to findpreference though), thanks for help anyways